# Is there a chrome extension that shows the HTTP Host header?

Tags: chrome

Is there a chrome extension that shows the HTTP Host header?

For example let's say I go http://webcode.me/

Wireshark shows what one would expect, which is that there is a Host header there

[image]

Chrome hides this

[image]

or if I do shift-f5 to ensure chrome doesn't take it from the cache

[image]

It doesn't really show that there is a header called "Host" that's there.

There is an extension called HTTP Header Spy, it doesn't show that there's a header called Host

[image]

Comment: Maybe there isn't.  Wireshark is fine, or I think a good thing to use is fiddler.

Comment: Here's a [link to Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica what would anybody do without you

Comment: Sorry, no offence meant (+1). I am sure that other readers of the question could Google for it, but, since I love Fiddler and use it regularly, it was trivial to add the link. Btw, as I am sure you know [postMan](https://www.postman.com/) is also awesome.